# Find and replace text in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I would like to find and replace a group of text in Excel using C#, moreover I want this replace to happen to text in the first row only.

I have used Google and found a few paid resource like Aspose API,Spire.Xls,etc, but I am looking for an open source resource or any other efficient way to achieve this. Please suggest.

Comment: Exactly, there is two main solution OpenXml (does not require Excel software to be installed) and the interop solution it use an instance of Excel to handle your file (so it require Excel to be installed)

So What did you try ?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Public static void ReplaceTextInExcelFile(string filename, string replace, string replacement)
{
    object m = Type.Missing;

    // open excel.
    Application app = new ApplicationClass();

    // open the workbook. 
    Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(
        filename,
        m, false, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m);

    // get the active worksheet. (Replace this if you need to.) 
    Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

    // get the used range. 
    Range r = (Range)ws.UsedRange;

    // call the replace method to replace instances. 
    bool success = (bool)r.Replace(
        replace,
        replacement,
        XlLookAt.xlWhole,
        XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
        true, m, m, m);

    // save and close. 
    wb.Save();
    app.Quit();
    app = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that worked for me

```
Excel.Range range = exWS.UsedRange;
range.Replace2("look_for", "replace", Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).